# sftp timeout issue in one direction only

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, nat

Summary:
I'm trying to connect from my laptop to my Desktop to transfer files using
`sftp username@localIP` but it gives me connection timeout

Case:
Both machines are using Linux and connected to the same router:
machine 1: Desktop connected to internet using a USB tethering phone connected to the same router as the second machine
machine 2: Laptop connected to internet using wireless

IP for each device using `hostname -I`:
Desktop: `192.168.42.130`
Laptop: `192.168.1.2`

Issue:
I can connect from Desktop to Laptop but not vice versa. I used it a lot from Desktop->Laptop but each time i try to connect from Laptop->Desktop this happens:
(takes 2 minutes)
(ssh: connect to host `192.168.42.130` port 22: Connection timed out
connection closed)

1) tried to set `GSPAuthentication` to no
2) tried to set `UseDNS` to no
3) restarted the service

But to no avail

Update:
Below are results after scanning for the issue (@A.B suggested that the problem is due to NAT)

Note: Len short for Lenovo (i.e.laptop)
Note: There are only two Linux machines on the router
Note: I have no wire so i use on my desktop a cell phone to connect to internet (using USB tethering)

1) connecting from Laptop->Desktop:
`omar@omar-Len:~/Desktop$ sftp omar@192.168.1.8 ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.8 port 22: Connection refused Connection closed`

2) Checking Desktop Address (before connection):
`omar@omar-LDesktop:~$ ip -brief address
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
enp0s25          DOWN
enp0s29f7u2      UNKNOWN        192.168.42.130/24 fe80::69ce:4a20:5a7e:433c/64`

3) on the laptop to check open connections (before connecting the two machines):
`omar@omar-Len:~/Desktop$ netstat -tn | egrep -w 22
omar@omar-Len:~/Desktop$`

(connected the two machines from pc->laptop)

4) checking open connection:
(Desktop)
`omar@omar-LDesktop:~$ netstat -tn | egrep -w 22
tcp 0 0 192.168.42.130:44644 192.168.1.2:22 ESTABLISHED`

(Laptop)
`omar@omar-Len:~/Desktop$ netstat -tn | egrep -w 22
tcp 0 0 192.168.1.2:22 192.168.1.8:44644 ESTABLISHED`

(Desktop)
`omar@omar-LDesktop:~$ ps -ef | grep [s]shd
root 30538 1 0 19:07 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D`

update 2: (I though of connecting the 2 machines through internet to avoid the NAT, so here is my trial)

I used `sftp -vvv <publicIP>@<LocalIP>`
to connect from Desktop->Laptop and it asked me for the password and when i entered it it returned back "Permission Denied" although it connects normal if i do not use the `<publicIP>`

Here is the debugging log from the Desktop: (note, i changed my `<publicIP>`)

`sftp -vvv <publicIP>@omar-@omar-Len@192.168.1.2
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.1.2" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.2 [192.168.1.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/omar/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/omar/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/omar/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/omar/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/omar/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/omar/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/omar/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/omar/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.2:22 as '<publicIP>@omar-@omar-Len'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/omar/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/omar/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: <hostKey>
SHA256:<SHA256>
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/omar/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/omar/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.2
debug1: Host '192.168.1.2' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/omar/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/omar/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/omar/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/omar/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/omar/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/omar/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/omar/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/omar/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/omar/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/omar/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/omar/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/omar/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/omar/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
<publicIP>@omar-@omar-Len@192.168.1.2's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.`

This is the debugging from the Laptop:
`May  4 14:59:39 omar-Len sshd[10133]: Invalid user <publicIP>@omar-@omar-Len from 192.168.1.8 port 56890
May  4 14:59:44 omar-Len sshd[10133]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
May  4 14:59:44 omar-Len sshd[10133]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.1.8
May  4 14:59:47 omar-Len sshd[10133]: Failed password for invalid user <publicIP>@omar-@omar-Len from 192.168.1.8 port 56890 ssh2
May  4 14:59:49 omar-Len sshd[10133]: Connection closed by invalid user <publicIP>@omar-@omar-Len 192.168.1.8 port 56890 [preauth]
May  4 15:03:50 omar-Len sudo:     omar : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/omar/Desktop ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/nano //var/log/auth.log
May  4 15:03:50 omar-Len sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May  4 15:04:12 omar-Len sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root`

Comment: if sshd is running on both boxes, this might be a firewall issue. Did you look for this ?

Comment: @A.B i have done `ss -tn sport = :22` and both showed the same resut `state  Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Ddress:Port  Peer Address:Port` only, no number or anything else

Comment: @tonioc i do not know how to use firewall in linux, i do not know how to check or what to check in the firewall

Comment: @A.B
omar@omar-Len:~/Desktop$ ss -tn | fgrep 192.168 | egrep 'ssh|22'
ESTAB  0         0               192.168.1.2:51134       173.194.76.188:5228    
ESTAB  0         0               192.168.1.2:22             192.168.1.8:44512

Comment: Well ... try to ssh to 192.168.1.8 rather than 192.168.42.130 . Looks that your method to get the correct IP is incomplete.

Comment: @A.B
omar@omar-Len:~/Desktop$ sftp omar@192.168.1.8
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.8 port 22: Connection refused
Connection closed

Comment: @A.B how to check for each ? (SSH Server, firewall, NAT)?

Comment: (so if some people read the comments, in the end that's indeed NAT. to be continued...)

Comment: ok, thank you but one last question, can i use sftp to connect to another devices that are not located on my local network? if so, then how because i searched a lot and did not find something useful

Comment: I realize I don't know how to help with this question. You didn't really state a goal. I'm done. I hope somebody has an other idea and know how to explain it (eg: ssh reverse tunnel). I wouldn't know how to explain.

Comment: thank you sir. have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

When you use tethering on the cellphone, it actually makes a local private network of its own and does NAT and stuff, hiding Desktop behind. That's why Desktop to laptop works fine as laptop is some public network for desktop, being accessible via the phone.

But that is not true for the other way round. There is no way for Laptop or modem can see and reach that network behind cellphone. Tethering has little to no options to cancel NAT and let basic routing to be done, unless you can bridge USB and wireless on it, there is not much you can do.

Any refusal or failed login you get is probably from the router or some hosts outside your network.

So the solution is to let desktop initiate connection all the time.

Comment: yes that is true, after i asked a friend, the only scenario to make it work is to add an exception to firewall and to add a static port to forward it to the device when anyone tried to connect through that port